# Struct has class reference then it will store on stack or heap C#

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

It is common knowledge that a struct is a value type, and is therefore allocated on the stack but when struct has class reference then it will stored on Stack or Heap.

```
 public class A {
       public int Value { get; set; }
    } 

    struct Rectangle
    {
        public int width;

        public int height;

        public A a;

    }      

 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Rectangle r ; // r will create on stack
            r.width = 5;  // it will create on stack as well,
            r.a = new A(); // but what about A object, it will stored on stack or heap, as i know class object it stored on heap, now it is inside the struct. 
        }
```

I know it is very common question, I have google it, didn't find right answer.
Thanks for in advance

Comment: Struct will be stored in a stack, with the value of `a`, which is a reference to an object in heap.

Comment: Inside a struct there will be a reference to object A (you can think of it like address), and the object itself is elsewhere (not embedded into struct).

Comment: The more interesting question is when a class has a field which is a struct. In that case, the struct is allocate inside the memory allocated for the class, which is on the heap. So "Structs are allocated on the stack" is an over-simplification: struct *local variables* are allocated on the stack (most of the time)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> struct is a value type, and is therefore allocated on the stack

This is incorrect. A more correct statement would be "value types can be stored on the stack", see the [truth about value types](https://ericlippert.com/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types/). The value type will *probably* be stored on the stack if given as a parameter, even if the jitter if free to store it wherever it damn pleases. But if the struct is part of a class, it will be stored on the heap, with all the other fields of the class.

Now, the reference to A will be stored as part of the struct, i.e. 8 bytes on x64. But the actual object it points to, including the `int Value`, will be stored on the heap.

Comment: What about a struct and if contains class variables? Am I correct to assume the struct and its variables will be stored on the stack, but the actual data of its class variables is stored on the heap?

Comment: @CyberMew If a struct contains a field of class type it will store the *reference* as part of the struct, but the actual object and any fields that is part of the object will be stored on the heap. But if the struct is a field in a class it will be stored on the heap as part of that class. The "structs are stored on the stack"-part is only true when passing/returning *parameters*,